# How Do I Change Keyboard Layout

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard

My keyboard can plug into my phone through USB. It has an American key layout.

How can I switch its layout to another layout (like using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> in Windows)?

Changing the layout of the on screen keyboard doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, there's an app for that. Several, actually, but apedroid is well-reviewed, currently being maintained, and has a free demo version if you want to make sure it works for your set-up.  $2-ish for the full version so "worst case" might be an overstatement.